# Hangman game coded in C++

Tags: c++, game, console, hangman

I have completed my hangman project in C++.

I would like your thoughts and improvements on my implementation.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string get_random_word(std::vector<std::string>& words);
void play();

std::vector<std::string> words = {"programming", "hangman", "games"};
// Credit for art - https://gist.github.com/chrishorton/8510732aa9a80a03c829b09f12e20d9c
std::string hangman_art[7] = {
    " +---+\n"
    " |   |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "==========",
    " +---+\n"
    " |   |\n"
    " O   |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "==========",
    " +---+\n"
    " |   |\n"
    " O   |\n"
    " |   |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "==========",
    " +---+\n"
    " |   |\n"
    " O   |\n"
    "/|   |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "==========",
    " +---+\n"
    " |   |\n"
    " O   |\n"
    "/|\\  |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "==========",
    " +---+\n"
    " |   |\n"
    " O   |\n"
    "/|\\  |\n"
    "/    |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "==========",
    " +---+\n"
    " |   |\n"
    " O   |\n"
    "/|\\  |\n"
    "/ \\  |\n"
    "     |\n"
    "=========="
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    std::cout << "Welcome to Hangman!\n";
    play();

    return 0;
}

void play()
{
    std::string secret_word = get_random_word(words);
    std::string guess_word = secret_word;
    for (int i = 0; i < secret_word.length(); ++i)
    {
        guess_word[i] = '_';
    }
    int try_no = 0;
    char guess;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << hangman_art[try_no] << "\n";
        std::cout << guess_word << "\n";
        std::cout << "Enter your guess:\n";
        std::cin >> guess;

        if (secret_word.find(guess) != std::string::npos)
            {   
                for (int i = 0; i < guess_word.length(); ++i)
                {
                    if (secret_word[i] == guess)
                    {
                        guess_word[i] = guess;
                    }
                }
            if (secret_word == guess_word)
            {
                std::cout << hangman_art[try_no] << "\n";
                std::cout << guess_word << "\n";
                std::cout << "You win! The word was " << secret_word << "\n";
                break;
            }
        } else {
            ++try_no;
        }
        if (try_no >= 6)
        {
            std::cout << hangman_art[try_no] << "\n";
            std::cout << guess_word << "\n";
            std::cout << "You lost! The word was " << secret_word << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

std::string get_random_word(std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    return words[rand() % words.size()];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks pretty good and kudos for not having `using namespace std;`

Here is some nitpicking.

Your indentation is all over the place, here you have an extra tab:

```cpp
if (secret_word.find(guess) != std::string::npos)
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < guess_word.length(); ++i)
```

And here you use a different convention:

```cpp
} else {
    ++try_no;
}
```

Create your functions in the order that they are called. Creating a class would be even better:

```cpp
class Hangman
{
public:
    void play();

private:
    std::string& get_random_word(std::vector<std::string>& words);
};
```

This part looks okay, and I would probably done it the same way, but if you really want to impress, you can use `std::find`

```cpp
auto index = std::find(secret_word.begin(), secret_word.end(), guess);
if (index != secret_word.end())
{
    do
    {
        guess_word[index - secret_word.begin()] = guess;
        index = std::find(index + 1, secret_word.end(), guess);
    } 
    while (index != secret_word.end());
}
else
{
    ++try_no;
}
```

You should always validate if reading from `stdin` was successful, consider adding this check.

```cpp
std::cin >> guess;
if (std::cin.fail())
    return;
```

Finally, it is very disappointing that nothing happens when you have won, consider creating an animation of a dancing man or something. It would also have been nice to see some ascii gore when you have lost =)

Answer (score 2):

This would be my feedback :

```
#include <iostream>
// #include <ctime> // removed this is not needed when using <random> header
#include <random>   // prefered random generator for C++, srand is more of a C left over.
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// best to put everything related to the game in a class

class Hangman final // this class is not supposed to be extended
{
    const unsigned int maximum_number_of_tries = 6;                     // to avoid "magic" constants in code

public:
    explicit Hangman(const std::vector<std::string>& words) :           // ANY constructor with only one parameter should be explicit (to avoid it being used as implicit type converter)
        m_random_generator{ std::random_device{}() },                   // initialize random generator C++ style
        m_distribution{ 0, words.size() - 1 },                          // initialize a uniform distribution with a range
        m_word_number{ m_distribution(m_random_generator) },            // extra variable for debugability
        m_secret_word{ words[m_word_number] },                          // pick a random word from the input
        m_guess_word{ std::string(m_secret_word.length(),'_') },        // initialize secret word with '_'
        m_try_no{ 0u }                                                  // consider renaming to "m_round"
    {
    }

    // todo : document
    void play()
    {
        bool won{ false };
        bool lost{ false };

        std::cout << "Welcome to Hangman!\n";

        // next line reads better then while true
        // good code documents itself, it tells a story.
        // so also use "small" functions to help
        // the code explain itself
        while (!won && !lost)
        {
            show_state();
            auto guess = make_guess();              // by making this a function you can easily add error checking later without changing the flow here.
            handle_guess(guess);                    // process the guess made by the user by updating the internal state of the guessed word.
            won = check_win();                      
            if (!won) lost = check_loss();
        }
    }

private:
    // static member function, no member variables are used
    static char make_guess()
    {
        char c;
        std::cout << "\nEnter your guess:\n";
        std::cin >> c;

        // todo check if c is a valid letter!
        return c;
    }

    // const member function, no member variables will be changed
    void show_state() const                                             
    {
        std::cout << "\n\n";
        std::cout << m_hangman_art[m_try_no] << "\n";
        std::cout << m_guess_word << "\n";
    }

    // cannot be a const method since members are modified.
    void handle_guess(char guess)
    {
        if (m_secret_word.find(guess) != std::string::npos)
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_guess_word.length(); ++i) // changed int to size_t
            {
                if (m_secret_word[i] == guess)
                {
                    m_guess_word[i] = guess;
                }
            }
        }
    
        // increase try number
        ++m_try_no;
    }

    bool check_win() const
    {
        if (m_secret_word != m_guess_word) return false;
    
        std::cout << m_hangman_art[m_try_no] << "\n";
        std::cout << m_guess_word << "\n";
        std::cout << "You win! The word was " << m_secret_word << "\n";
        return true;
    }

    bool check_loss() const
    {
        if (m_try_no < maximum_number_of_tries) return false;           

        std::cout << m_hangman_art[m_try_no] << "\n";
        std::cout << m_guess_word << "\n";
        std::cout << "You lost! The word was " << m_secret_word << "\n";
        return true;
    }

    std::mt19937 m_random_generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> m_distribution;
    std::size_t m_word_number;
    std::string m_secret_word;
    std::string m_guess_word;
    unsigned int m_try_no;

    // Credit for art - https://gist.github.com/chrishorton/8510732aa9a80a03c829b09f12e20d9c
    // static because this art is the same for all instances of Hangman
    const std::string m_hangman_art[7] = {
        " +---+\n"
        " |   |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "==========",
        " +---+\n"
        " |   |\n"
        " O   |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "==========",
        " +---+\n"
        " |   |\n"
        " O   |\n"
        " |   |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "==========",
        " +---+\n"
        " |   |\n"
        " O   |\n"
        "/|   |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "==========",
        " +---+\n"
        " |   |\n"
        " O   |\n"
        "/|\\  |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "==========",
        " +---+\n"
        " |   |\n"
        " O   |\n"
        "/|\\  |\n"
        "/    |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "==========",
        " +---+\n"
        " |   |\n"
        " O   |\n"
        "/|\\  |\n"
        "/ \\  |\n"
        "     |\n"
        "=========="
    };
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::string> words = { "programming", "hangman", "games" };
    Hangman game{ words };
    game.play();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a Mersenne Twister for hangman is a bit extreme =). If I did choose to use it, I would create a helper class to remove the complexities from the hangman class, something like this: [TIO](https://bit.ly/3Arm5N6)

Comment: Maybe it is ;) And yes encapsulating complexity is always a good idea. But I also think that learning c++ should also involve learning about the standard library and what's in it.